# (Java)Calculating the number of years to get to a specific balance

Tags: java

Here's the prompt:

There is a bank account that earns 5 percent interest per year. The initial account balance is $10000. Given a target balance (for example, $20000), return the number of years that it takes for the account balance to reach the target balance. The number of years should be an integer.

Here's my code:

```
public int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance){
  int years = 1;
  for (double balance = 10000.0; balance <= targetBalance; years++) {
    double multiplier = Math.pow(1.05, years);
    balance *= multiplier;
  }
  return years;
}
```

When this runs, [multiplier] increases by the following pattern:

```
1.05^1 --> (1.05^1)^2 --> ((1.05^1)^2)^3 --> etc.
```

How do I fix my code so that [multiplier] increases by the following pattern:

```
1.05^1 --> 1.05^2 --> 1.05^3 --> etc?
```

Comment: You get 5% for 1 year, right? So why `double multiplier = Math.pow(1.05, years);`? You'd basically just want to to `balance *= 1.05` since you're already doing this for one year after another. - It seems you mixed the two methods of calculating the balance for `x` years: 1) iterate over the year and multiply the balance by interest rate or 2) calcualate `finalBalanace = initialBalance * Math.pow(1.05,x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to increase the multiplier - every year carries the same interest, and you just need to keep multiplying by the same interest rate every year:

```java
public int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance) {
  int years = 1;
  double multiplier = 1.05;
  for (double balance = 10000.0; balance < targetBalance; years++) {
    balance *= multiplier;
  }
  return years;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As a side note, this can be solved without a loop, by extracting a log of both sides of the equation:

10000 * 1.05<sup>year</sup> = target
1.05<sup>year</sup> = target / 10000
log(1.05<sup>year</sup>) = log(target / 10000)
year * log(1.05) = log(target / 10000)
year = log(target / 10000) / log(1.05)

Or, in java:

```java
public int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance) {
    double years = Math.log(targetBalance / 10000) / Math.log(1.05);
    return (int) Math.ceil(year);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `balance * Math.pow(1.05, years)` that means you directly apply the increase for `years`, you want to go year by year, so just use the `1.05`.

Also for that kind of problem, a `while` loop is prefered

```
public static int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance) {
    int years = 1;
    double balance = 10000;
    while (balance <= targetBalance) {
        balance *= 1.05;
        years++;
    }
    return years;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the answer in years. You can test it in excel by adding some formulas, the result is correct:

public class practice {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    double interestRate = 0.05;
    double initialAmount = 10000.00;
    double targetValue = 20000.00;
    int numYears = 0;
    
    while(targetValue > initialAmount) {
        
        initialAmount += (initialAmount * interestRate);
        numYears++;
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("Year to hit target: " + numYears);
    System.out.println("Final Amount: " + initialAmount);
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop instead of for.

```
public int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance){
    int years = 1;
    double balance = 10000.0;
    while (1) {
        if ( balance * 1.05 * years >= targetBalance) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            years++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return years;
}
```

But you should consider on what happens to the interest earned on a year, is it being added to the current balance or added separately. If it is being added to the starting balance of the account consider following code.

```
 public int getNumberOfYears(double targetBalance){
        int years = 0;
        double balance = 10000.0;
        while (balance < targetBalance ) {
            balance *= 1.05;
            years ++;
        }
        return years;
    }
```